# Почему не могу добавить новый внешний ключ?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

yii2, пытаюсь сделать миграцию для добавления внешнего ключа:

```
    $this->addForeignKey(
        'fk-subordination-sub_id',
        'subordination',
        'sub_id',
        'storage',
        'id',
        'CASCADE'
    );
```

возвращает ошибку:

```
Exception: SQLSTATE[23000]: 
Integrity constraint violation:
1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
(`images`.`#sql-5a0_1f3`, CONSTRAINT `fk-subordination-sub_id` FOREIGN KEY (`sub_id`) REFERENCES `storage` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

однако, если добавляю другой ключ:

```
    $this->addForeignKey(
        'fk-subordination-sub_id',
        'subordination',
        'sub_id',
        'user',
        'id',
        'CASCADE'
    );
```

то все работает нормально. все ключи int(11), отличий в создании не было (кроме создания pk), создавал так же через миграции:

subordination:

```
    $this->createTable('subordination', [
        'chief_id' => $this->integer(11),
        'sub_id' => $this->integer(11),
    ]);
    $this->addColumn('subordination', 'id', $this->primaryKey());
```

storage:

```
    $this->createTable('storage', [
        'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
        'name' => $this->string(),
        'photograph_id' => $this->integer(11)
    ])
```

в чем может быть проблема? mariaDB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Невозможно добавить ограничение внешнего ключа, потому что оно сбойнёт. Другими словами - в таблицах уже имеются данные, которые не соответствуют создаваемому ключу и будут вызывать ошибку целостности.

Так что сначала "выровняйте" данные, а потом создавайте внешний ключ.